# How to get desired sorting output in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the object inside an array below in ascending order by it value and get the desired output as below:-

```
var arr = [{"DOA Qty":"0.000665921017598927382910198160","LOS%":"0","FID Valid EC By Part":"0.0041860443283016713761966","Interventions":"0"}]
```

Desired output - sort in ascending order by value:

```
var desiredarr =[{"LOS%":"0","Interventions":"0","DOA Qty":"0.000665921017598927382910198160","FID Valid EC By Part":"0.0041860443283016713761966"}]


let sorteddataarr: any = Object.values(arr[0]).sort(function (a, b) { return arr[a] - arr[b]; });

alert(JSON.stringify(sorteddataarr));  // not giving result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[1]-b[1]` **==** :ASEC

`b[1]-a[1]` **==** :DESC

Try this :

```js
var obj = 
{
 "DOA Qty":"0.000665921017598927382910198160",
 "LOS%":"0",
 "FID Valid EC By Part":"0.0041860443283016713761966",
 "Interventions":"0"
}

var entries = Object.entries(obj)
entries.sort(function(a,b){return a[1]-b[1]});

obj = {};
entries.map(function(item){
 obj[item[0]] = item[1];
})
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: you need to convert the values of the object to numbers as currently they are strings. And if you check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and look for "order" you'll see that there is no guarantee of the order of the keys in an object so your result is basically the same as what you started with.

Comment: Yeah i know an object can't really sorted, and i can  just return `entries` after the sort method, can also use this `var entries = Object.values(obj)
values.sort();` to get the sorted array of the values, and the conversion to int isn't really the problem here.

Comment: entries.sort(function(a,b){return a[1]-b[1]});  // getting error like entreries must be of type number.

Comment: When ? did you try running the snippet above ? it works fine.

Comment: The following would make some sense since Map.prototype.keys is in the order that they were set: `Object.entries(obj).sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1])
.reduce((result,[key,value])=>result.set(key,value),new Map())
`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will help, the keys of an object are given in no particular order when doing things like `Object.keys` or `for something in ...`, since the order is important to you I converted the object(s) to array(s) of key(s) and value(s):

```js
var arr = [{"DOA Qty":"0.000665921017598927382910198160","LOS%":"0","FID Valid EC By Part":"0.0041860443283016713761966","Interventions":"0"}];

console.log(
  arr.map(
    object=>
      Object.keys(object).map(
        key=>[Number(object[key]),key]//your values are not numbers, maybe create better JSON
      ).sort(
        ([a],[b])=>a-b
      )
      //optional, if you rather have [key,value] .map(([value,key])=>[key,value]
  )
)
```

Comment: can we sort by value in ascending order and then put their respective keys according to sorted values in a map to get desiredarr[].

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr I don't know what you mean, can you update the question with input and desired output?

Comment: I mean first we sort map in ascending order according to values in map and then put their corresponding keys alongwith sorted values in a map.

Comment: @Ahmadmnzr Still don't know what you mean, can you provide input with objects that have only 2 keys (simple objects) and desired output in your question? Currently you provide an object with "sorted" keys as desired output but that doesn't do anything since there is no guarantee of the order the keys/values of an Object are given in ES, it may work by accident but can break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple compare function. 
Define the key to use in the function. I used value

Then call Array.prototype.sort() and pass in your compare function

The only difference between the two for DESC or ASC order is that the greater than and less than symbols are switched

```js
function compareDESC(a, b) {
  if (a.value < b.value)
    return 1;
  if (a.value > b.value)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

function compareASC(a, b) {
  if (a.value > b.value)
    return 1;
  if (a.value < b.value)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

var arr = [
  {
    value: 2
  },
  {
    value: 6
  },
  {
    value: 3
  },
  {
    value: 8
  },
  {
    value: 9
  },
  {
    value: 4
  },
];

arr.sort(compareDESC)
console.log(arr)
arr.sort(compareASC)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Simpler would be to do: `arr.sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value)` for ascending and `b.value-a.value` for descending

Comment: That works but it is not as reusable nor as readable. Also, I don't know if the OP is using babel or not to use the arrow functions.

Comment: If you're looking for re usability and readability then have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zposhrxp/) example. Using partially applied functions for these sort of tasks will get easily get you to do complex things with little effort.